# Operator overloading on temporary object

Tags: c++

im trying to perform operator overloading on a temporary object like in this example:

```
class changeStrToInt
{
public:
     int operator()(std::string x) {
         return 10;
     }
};


int main()
{
    changeStrToInt obj; //works
    int i = obj("lala");

    int x = changeStrToInt("lala"); // doesnt work
}
```

So my question is how can i make int x = changeStrToInt("lala"); work?

Comment: Why does it need to be an object instead of a function?

Comment: you are going to use something like the constructor, but operators are completely different and work as expected in your first line of code.

Comment: With your current implementation `int x = changeStrToInt()("lala");` would work. To make it work "like a function" you'd need to provide an overloaded constructor and `operator int()`

Comment: UnholySeep:
Thanks thats what i meant. ... i was curious if its possible. Also for example in Unreal Engine there are structs such as FVector, and it's used as ex. FVector(10) and then put into a function, i wonder how it's done as constructors dont return anything?

Comment: `FVector(10)` constructs an object. If a function takes an `FVector` as a parameter you can just construct it at the call site - that's called an "unnamed object". There is no need for any kind of operator overloading for that to work

Answer (score 1):

`changeStrToInt("lala")` tries to call constructor of `changeStrToInt` with `"lala"`.

You want:

- `changeStrToInt()("lala")`
- or `changeStrToInt{}("lala")`